# How to second select via first select value onload

Tags: jquery

I have two selects:

```html
<select name="iam" id="iam">
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <option value="1">Driver</option>
    <option value="2">Traveler</option>
    <option value="3">Sender</option>
</select>   
<select name="look" id="look">
    <option value="">Выберайте</option>
    <option value="1" id="driver">Driver</option>
    <option value="2" id="traveler">Traveller</option>
    <option value="4" id="post">Post</option>
</select>
```

This is working but it is not working when page loaded. What i want to show second select if first select has value, during the validation process

```js
$('#iam').on('load change selected blur', function() {
  $('#look').prop('selectedIndex', 0);
  if ($(this).val() == 1) {
    $("#look").show();
    $("#look #driver").hide();
    $("#look #traveler").show();
    $("#look #post").show();
  } else if ($(this).val() == 2) {
    $("#look").show();
    $("#look #driver").show();
    $("#look #traveler").hide();
    $("#look #post").show();
  }
})
```

Comment: Its not clear what do you want to achieve.

Comment: why would first select have value when page just loads?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('#iam').on('load change selected blur', function() {
        $('#look').prop('selectedIndex',0);
        if ($(this).val() == 1) {
            $("#look").show(); 
            $("#look #driver").hide();
            $("#look #traveler").show();
            $("#look #post").show();
        } else if ($(this).val() == 2) {
            $("#look").show(); 
            $("#look #driver").show();
            $("#look #traveler").hide();
            $("#look #post").show();
        } 
 }


$('#iam').change();
```

Call the change method on first drop down on page load.

Comment: I did know so easy :)